# Power BI: is there a way to "filter" all the queries of my model based on one query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a master data file/query that has all the informations including ID that i need to analyse (in-scope products).
All my other files/queries have the said ID but also for products not in scope.

Is there a way to easily make power  BI analyse in the dashboard only the products with the ID in the master data query. filter based on ID present in master data query by using the master data query as a mapping table.

I have linked all tables together but it still shows the ID that are not in scope as blank

Comment: Did you add any filter or just joined things together?

Answer (score 0):

You can....you'd need to have a relationship between your master data table and the other tables using a common ID column.  If the tables are already all linked together, then you can create a measure to filter out the data based on the presence of the ID in the master data query.
so you'd

- create a new measure in one of the related tables....say a sales table.
  something kinda like:

```
    FilteredSales = 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[SalesAmount] ),
        NOT ISBLANK ( RELATED ( MasterData[ID] ) )
)
```

replace the table and column names as needed.

- then you can use that measure to display on the data for the products with an id in the master data table.

please note, this working will be highly dependent on the correct relationship between your master data table and the other tables using the id column